# Installed Ubuntu next to Windows 10 caused nothing to boot anymore

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi, windows-10

The following broke my PC.

1. Installed Windows 10 Education x64 final release
2. Booted Ubuntu 15.04 install disc
3. Installed Ubuntu with option to install next to Windows
4. Installation said it has been completed
5. After restarting the computer, GRUB appears and I can select between Ubuntu and Windows
6. Neither Ubuntu nor Windows boot successfully

Windows stucks with black screen and no information visible.
Ubuntu stucks with its typical pink/purple background and the capslock light on the keyboard is on. (Edit: Kernal panic, see below)

What have I already done / what are my settings?

1. I turned off Secure Boot (before the installation)
2. I turned off Fast Boot (before the installation)
3. I used GPT and UEFI mode for both Windows and Ubuntu
4. Legacy Mode is off

Necessary to note

1. I used one disc for everything (I only have one)
2. Both GRUB and Windows Boot Manager are visible in the Boot Menu of my PC
3. I tried to repair using Boot Repair (on the Ubuntu live disc) but [errors appear](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11966873/)

Is there any chance to rescue my installation?
If not, what should I do different the next time? Is Ubuntu unable to be installed next to Windows 10 because of its fresh release?

**Kernel panic**: After booting in Ubuntu rescue mode, I noticed the following kernel panic:

```
VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0)
```

Here are my current partitions (after the installation). The first four partitions have been created by the Windows 10 installer.[image: Current partitions]

Comment: Windows is Windows.  When you installed Ubuntu you configured Grub, which boots into the detected Windows Bootloader, which hasn't changed significantly for a very long time   Why didn't you just shrink the partition then create the additional partitions that way.  Your last paragraph is confusing, you might need to, provide us screenshots of the partition of your disk.

Comment: I am not an expert. I didn't know that I can shrink an existing partition. Ignore my last paragraph. I attached a screenshot to the first post with an explanation of the partitions. Also I noticed an error message when trying to boot in Ubuntu rescue mode. It is also in the first post. I wonder why this seems to affect Windows also...

Comment: You typically have to repair the Windows bootloader after you install Ubuntu, that isn't all that unusual.

Comment: How? I tried it using Boot Repair, but it fails (as I've linked above on paste.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Are you sure you installed both operating systems in EFI mode?  The existence of that reserved partition says otherwise.  Ubuntu is failing trying to mount that partition infact.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I created the bootable USB drive using Rufus and set the mode to "GPT and UEFI". I double checked and made a photo of my BIOS / UEFI, where everything (the third entry is my USB drive) is on the UEFI list: http://i.imgur.com/6SC19LA.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26442/discussion-between-ramhound-and-the-wavelength).

Comment: The presence of a [Microsoft Reserved partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) does *not* indicate a BIOS-mode installation. The opposite, in fact; it's present only on GPT disks, which Windows can boot only in EFI mode. The Windows boot may have to be repaired using Windows tools. The Ubuntu `unable to mount` message probably indicates a missing or damaged `initrd` file. It may be best to re-install Ubuntu -- but use the "Something Else" option, manually specify the existing Ubuntu partition, and tell the installer to reformat that partition.

Comment: I reinstalled and with "Something Else" option everything worked fine. Thanks.